# No conversion from "const char" to "int"

Tags: c++, pointers

The following is the problem code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

void convertToUppercase(char *);

int main()
{
    char phrase[] = "characters and $32.98";

    cout << "The phrase before conversion is : " << phrase;
    convertToUppercase(phrase);
    cout << "\nThe phrase after conversion is : " << phrase << endl;
    return 0;
}

void convertToUppercase(char *sPtr)
{
    while (*sPtr != "\0")
    {
        if (islower(*sPtr))
            *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr);

        cout << "sPtr (before) = " << sPtr;
        sPtr++;
        cout << "\nsPtr (after) = " << sPtr << endl;
    }
}
```

The output window shows me that :

```
1>d:\sync files\converting lowercase letter to uppercase letters\converting lowercase letter to uppercase letters\main.cpp(19): error C2446: '!=' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'
1>          There is no context in which this conversion is possible
1>d:\sync files\converting lowercase letter to uppercase letters\converting lowercase letter to uppercase letters\main.cpp(19): error C2040: '!=' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char [2]'
```

Where is the mistake I made? I have exactly copied the code from my book but the problem still exists.

Sorry, I cannot find it out. need Help.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Your convert function should be a single `std::transform` call or ranged-for loop. You don't need to check that it's lower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your while condition should check `*sPTR != '\0'`, `"\0"` is of type `const char*`
2. If `toupper` is passed a negative value, you invoke UB, so make sure to call it with `static_cast<unsigned char>` ([Details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21805674/do-i-need-to-cast-to-unsigned-char-before-calling-toupper))
3. You do not need to check `islower`, `toupper` already does that
4. Make your life easier, use `std::string`:

   ```
   void convertToUpper (std::string& str) {
    for (auto& v:str)
        v = toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(v));
   }
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Simple, your comparison is wrong.

```
while (*sPtr != "\0")
```

should be

```
while (*sPtr != '\0')
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
while (*sPtr != '\0')
```

You may also get a seg fault for modifying a string constant

Answer (score 3):

The condition of your `while` loop is wrong, you need to write `while(*sPtr != '\0')` with single quotes.

Explanation: `'\0'` is a single character, `"\0"` is a string constant, i. e. an array of two characters in this case.

There are also shorter ways to write your loop condition:

1. You can just use a plain zero instead of `'\0'`: `while(*sPtr != 0)`
2. You can even omit the comparison since you are comparing to zero: `while(*sPtr)`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to compare a `char` to a `char const*` (well, really a `char const[2]` but that's just a detail). You probably meant to use

```
while (*sPtr != '\0')
```

or

```
while (*sPtr)
```

Note that your use of `islower()` and `toupper()` isn't guaranteed to work: the argument to these functions has to be positive but `char` may have negative values. You need to first convert the `char` to `unsigned char`:

```
toupper(static_cast<unsigned char>(*sPtr))
```

The test for `islower()` isn't needed: on non-lower `char`s `toupper()` just returns the argument. Omitting the trst is improving the oerformance.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is change `while (*sPtr != "\0")` to `while (*sPtr != '\0')`. You're trying to compare a char to a string. I agree with @chris, though, you don't need to check if it's lower case. It's just messy to do so, and it won't decrease the running time of your algorithm.