# char pointer comparison error

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char

Using C++ MFC and Visual Studio 2008.

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm not sure why this isn't working. I'm making a function that finds the standard illegal characters for XML in a `char *` that's passed to it, but I get a strange error.

```
char* XMLIllegalCharacterParser(char *input){
    char *Temp;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
        if(input[i] == "\"" || input[i] == "\'" || input[i] == "&")
    }
    return Temp;
}

1>.\FileImport.cpp(868) : error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't working. What syntax do I have wrong?

PS: I know that I only have 3 of the characters there. I got this error and I wanna fix it before I add the other two.

Here my after code:

```
char* XMLIllegalCharacterParser(char *input){
char *Temp;
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++){
    switch(input[i]){
        case '\"':
            strcat_s(Temp, 6, "&quot;");
            break;
        case '\'':
            strcat_s(Temp, 6, "&apos;");
            break;
        case '&':
            strcat_s(Temp, 5, "&amp;");
            break;
        case '<':
            strcat_s(Temp, 4, "&lt;");
            break;
        case '>':
            strcat_s(Temp, 4, "&gt;");
            break;
        default:
            strcat_s(Temp, 1, (const char*)input[i]);
            break;
    }
}
return Temp;
}
```

Comment: Don't take a non-const `char *` when you don't modify it. That just limits how people can call your function (which is, imo, very frustrating). Anyway, your `if` statement has no body and since this is C++, use `std::string`.

Comment: Also, when doing single character comparison use the single quote `'`, like `input[i] == '&'`

Comment: Yeah, I didn't include the body just yet. Now that I have the solution to the error, I'll have a proper body soon.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303100/no-conversion-from-const-char-to-int

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably mean single quotes instead of double:

```
input[i] == '"'
            ^ ^
```

Same goes for the other cases. When you use double quotes, as in "&", you create a "string literal". But `input[i]` is a character: you can't compare a string literal with a character.

What's more, even if `input[i]` would also be a string literal, that wouldn't be the right way to compare c-style strings in C++.

Comment: This is a correct answer. It would be a good answer if it also included the *why.*

Comment: Thank you! This solved it right up. The function is a first draft and will be expanded soon, but that solved my major issue.

Comment: I would argue `==` is the right to compare strings in C++. You just have to use the right type for your string instead of making life harder for yourself.

Comment: @chris I made explicit that I meant c-style strings.

Comment: @chris: Curious thing C++ people cannot remember the namespace of their string class and insist on decorating the name of the inherited and commonly used one instead. Still, somehow beside the point imho.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's because in proper C++, C-style strings are not commonly, but **very rarely** used. You don't want to touch a nul-terminated `char` array unless you're dealing with a C API.

Comment: @Angew Or you need a string literal of any persuasion (narrrow, wide, utf8, utf16, utf32, what-have-you). Like, for initializing a C++ `std::string`. So, all the time...

Comment: @Deduplicator I could have been a bit more explicit - you don't want to touch a string explicitly referred to by a `const char*` or `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing a `char` to strings. Change this line:

```
if (input[i] == '"' || input[i] == '\'' || input[i] == '&')
```